# How can I code in C rather than php for website work?

Tags: php, c

I am yearning to code in C for website work. C or C++ or whatever. Even C-- will do :)

I got weary of all those $ of .php.

I know this would not significantly speed up websites, as most server power is spent outside of code, on database accesses, but still. I want my Ferrari back!, my beloved C!

Is there a way out? Is there any hope?

Comment: I would like to see some more explanation on what exactly you want to achieve? What kind of answer would you like? Simply Yes or No?

Comment: You'll put your compiled executable files in your `cgi-bin` folder of your webserver, and configure your webserver to serve cgi's.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the question. He just wants to be able to program his websites directly in C and is asking if it is possible and how. Voting for reopening.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós: Thank you, will keep it in mind. Wordpress.exe coming soon :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways, one of them is CppCMS, a C++ web framework:

http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/main/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CppCMS

Comment: He said that "even C-- will do", read his question (first line).

Comment: Ah you beat me, my bad ...

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am going through the website. But the first impression was, it felt a bit lonely, especially the 'who uses CppCMS' page. Still, I will go through every bit of the documentation, just reading it feels good.

Comment: It feels that way because there are really few scenarios where you want to fully develop an website in C++, but don't let that fool you, the framework is pretty evolved.

Comment: @Paul,looking at the hello example, (http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_tut_hello), I must admit I freaked out :). A mixture of classes, class extensions, port numbers, compiler options and on top of that a content framework and a class structure I would have to agree with. Too much to replace echo 'hello'. Who knows in a few years, they may evolve into something easier and be the next big thing. For the moment, it is really valuable IF one needs to use c++ in a website setting: They have the code, the experience and the wiki.